# reusable custom-filter components reset after dropdownlist lost focus

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, angular5

I'm trying to use the example of [Reusable Custom-Filter Components](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/reusable-filter/). If I check the provided Plunker example I changed the filter. After I clicked somewhere else the filter is reseted to default item. How can I achieve that the filter stays so I can do other stuff on grid?

Here an excerpt from package.json:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.4",
"@angular/common": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~5.0.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~5.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.4.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^1.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^1.2.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^1.6.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.3.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.5",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.43.2",
"angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
"angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
"angular2-toaster": "^4.0.1",
"animate.css": "3.5.2",
"awesome-bootstrap-checkbox": "1.0.0",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
"cldr-data": "^32.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"glyphicons-halflings": "1.9.0",
"ng2-redux": "^5.1.2",
"ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.5",
"pace": "git://github.com/HubSpot/pace.git#v0.7.7",
"popper.js": "1.12.5",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
"rxjs": "^5.5.0",
"tassign": "^1.0.0",
"widgster": "0.0.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the DropDownList losing the value on blur, but it is fixed in the latest version of the DropDowns package:

[DOCS Changelog](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/dropdowns/changelog/)

Upgrading to the latest versions of the Kendo UI for Angular packages should resolve the described problem.